# Autoboxing for String in java

Tags: java, primitive-types, autoboxing

```
Integer l = Integer.valueOf("100");   // valid no compilation
Integer l = "100";   //Error : cannot convert from string to integer
```

Why I am facing the above error please suggest to me. (Need to use Autoboxing concept for second line)

Comment: Autoboxing only works for primitives. `String` is not a primitive. I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic of autoboxing, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 4):

Any value in quotes in java is treated as a `String`, and strings are objects, Auto-boxing is not supported in `JAVA` for Objects, So If you need then you have to do explicitly.

auto-boxing is only allowed from primitives to it's wapper classes.

The following table lists the primitive types and their corresponding wrapper classes, which are used by the Java compiler for auto-boxing and unboxing:

```
Primitive type  Wrapper class
boolean         Boolean 
byte            Byte 
char            Character 
float           Float 
int             Integer 
long            Long 
short           Short 
double          Double
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: I wanted to do autoboxing for string the same as I have done in the first line.

Comment: Integer.valueOf(String) is not auto boxing. It is a method call.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this is not called an [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) but is an ordinary static method call with a `String` as a parameter. The simplest examples of autoboxing are:

```
Integer i = 1;
Character ch = 'a';
```

Your snippet tries to instantiate a `String` as an `Integer` which are in the Java world incompatible types. Autoboxing happens only for the primitive data types.

```
Integer l = "100";  // Cannot convert from String to Integer 
Integer l = 100;    // Autoboxing happens
```

Answer (score 2):

From [JLS, §5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> Boxing conversion converts expressions of **primitive type** to corresponding expressions of reference type. [...]

`"100"` in Java is of type `String`. `String` is not a primitive and therefore boxing does not apply.